# Нужно запустить функцию после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Пробовал запустить функцию с помощью onload и DOMContentLoaded, но ничего не работает...

JS:

```
    function lk(){
    alert(auth);
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      lk();
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <body onload="lk()">
```

Comment: Как вы JS подключаете? Это полный код?

Comment: О господи... Я забыл подключить... Спасибо большое

Answer (score -1):

Похоже, у вас не объявлена переменная `auth`.
Попробуйте добавить первой строкой `let auth = 'hello';` или замените `alert(auth);` на `alert('hello');`.

Comment: Не помогло.. Auth беру из php ` var auth = '<?= $auth?>';`

Comment: Покажите весь код. Так не понятно.